# Deleting a line in a file that matches the person that logs out

Tags: java, file, jsp

I have a problem with a piece of code that I have found here from one of the answered questions.

this is my code:

```
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
             throws ServletException, IOException 
             {
                boolean logout = false;
                RequestDispatcher rd = null;
                Cookie[] c = req.getCookies();
                String name;
                for(Cookie cookie: c)
                {
                    if(cookie.getName().equals("cUsername"))
                    {
                        name = cookie.getValue();
                    }
                }



            if(req.getParameter("logout") != null)
            {
                logout = true;
                rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("loginpagina.jsp");
                rd.forward(req, resp);
            }
            if(logout)
            {               

                File inputFile = new File("C://Users/Jacco_000/Desktop/LoggedUser.txt");
                File tempFile = new File("C://Users/Jacco_000/Desktop/tempfile.txt");

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

                String lineToRemove = "cUsername";
                String currentLine;

                while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                    if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove))
                    {
                    writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
                    }
                }
                writer.close();
                reader.close();

                tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);



            }

        }   

 }
```

what is does is, it logs out a user that is logged in on a website. The loged in users are saved in a file called `"LoggedUsers.txt"`. What is want is when I log out that the name that is logging out will be removed from the file without the rest of the names that are logged in being removed as well because that is whats happening now.

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you realize that when two users log out at the same moment that you have a concurrency problem with this kind implementation, regardless of the getting the fix done or not.

Comment: For right now it doesn't matter if 2 people log out at the exact same moment. whats happening right now is that when im logged in with 2 users and i log out with only one, it deletes both users from the file regardless which user it is. if it would be 3 users then it would still delete all users if i only log out with one

Comment: Your problem description is clear about that @Jake, just saying that the solution to your problem will not solve thread-safety issues in the algorithm. But I guess you don't care about that right now.

Answer (score 1):

As per your condition, you are re-writing the user name to be logged out and the rest are skipped. All you need is to reverse your condition:

```
if(!trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove))// use !
{
    writer.write(currentLine);
}
```

***Edited:***

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
 String name = null;
// to do rest
if(!trimmedLine.equals(name))// use !
{
    writer.write(trimmedLine);
    writer.newLine();// add, if required
}
```

In your `LoginServlet.java` you have not drop the cookie:

```
if(loginSucces)
{
    Cookie c1 = new Cookie("cUsername", name);
    Cookie c2 = new Cookie("cPassword", pass);
    resp.addCookie(c1);//you are missing this line
    rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("Welkom.jsp");
}
```

> the only problem that remains right now is that when i log back in the
>   users username appears double in the loggedusers file

Problem seems to be in `LoginServlet.java`, you have `userLijst` list tracking logged in users, since you never removed the logged out user from the list it gets written into file as many times you re-login. Either you should skip using the list or you may put one more check if the list contains the logged in user like:

```
if(name != null && !name.isEmpty() && !userLijst.contains(name) && pass != null && !pass.isEmpty()) {
  // 
 }
```

**P.S.** storing password in cookie is a bad idea.

Comment: Doesn't work :(. what it's doing now is it is writing anull bnull in the temporary file.

thanks for the quick awnser though!

Comment: The cookie is used to remember the users username so it can be displayed on the page as he logs in. im trying to use the cookies given name ("cUsername") to remove the line in the file that i want to remove.

Comment: I did. thanks for the updates. added the addcookie bit. The password was never stored because it was never used haha.

edited the nme to name. allready thought that it should be name. right now its giving an error saying that it is not initialized. if i would write null at string name; then the code wouldnt run because no user is named null

Comment: Progress has been found. made a user named null and now when i log out with null it only deletes null from the file. so what i have to do basicly is finding a way that string name will be the name of the user that is logged in with the cookie

Comment: Works now. it deletes the user and leaves the other users untouched. the only problem that remains right now is that when i log back in the users username appears double in the loggedusers file.

Example:
I log in with user A & B.

loggedusers:
A
B

i log out with A:

loggedusers:
B

i relog:

loggedusers:
A
B
A

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to write the username to loggedusers.txt as it logs in:

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private ArrayList userLijst = new ArrayList();

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
         throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            boolean loginSucces = false;
            String name = req.getParameter("username");
            String pass = req.getParameter("password");

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("C://Users/Jacco_000/Desktop/LoggedUser.txt"));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            if(!name.isEmpty() && name != null &&  !pass.isEmpty() && pass != null)
            {
                File f = new File("C://Users/Jacco_000/Desktop/users.txt");
                if(f.exists() && f.isFile())
                {
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
                    sc.useDelimiter(",");
                    while(sc.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        String s = sc.nextLine();
                        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(s);
                        sc2.useDelimiter(",");

                        String nm = sc2.next();
                        String ps = sc2.next();
                        String rnm = sc2.next();
                        String em = sc2.next();
                        String ad = sc2.next();
                        String ld = sc2.next();


                        if(name.contains(nm) && pass.contains(ps))
                        {
                            loginSucces = true;
                            String loggedUsers = nm;
                            userLijst.add(loggedUsers);
                            for(int i = 0; i < userLijst.size(); i++)
                            {
                                out.write(userLijst.get(i));
                                out.newLine();
                            }
                            out.close();
                            fw.close();

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                loginSucces = false;
            }   

            RequestDispatcher rd = null;

            if(!loginSucces)
            {
                req.setAttribute("msgs", "Gebruikersnaam en/of Wachtwoord is incorrect");
                rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("loginpagina.jsp");
            }


            if(req.getParameter("register") != null)
            {
                rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("registerpagina.jsp");
            }

            if(loginSucces)
            {
                Cookie c1 = new Cookie("cUsername", name);
                Cookie c2 = new Cookie("cPassword", pass);
                rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("Welkom.jsp");
            }

            rd.forward(req, resp);
```